# How can I use Web Redirection Service of Crossbar?

Tags: redirect, crossbar

I am trying to redirect a http request (GET), using Crossbar's Redirection Service. I am using 'curl' for the request. Redirection seems to work fine, but i can't pass my (query) parameters to the final destination. Specifically, I am doing:

```
curl -L "http://localhost:8008/redirection?num=15"
```

where at localhost:8008 is running the crossbar router. The path '/redirection' is defined at the configuration file of Crossbar:

```
"redirection":{
    "type": "redirect",
    "url": "http://somewhere.com/something" 
},
```

The response from the server (e.g. http://somewhere.com/something) is:

```
{
 "detail": "Missing query parameter 'num'",
 "status": 400,
 "title": "Bad Request",
 "type": "about:blank"
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I am not sure if this is the correct way, but it is working. I added some lines of code at the file **http.py**, which is at the path: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/twisted/web. Specifically, i changed the function redirect of the class Request, as shown below:

```
    def redirect(self, url):
    """
    Utility function that does a redirect.

    The request should have finish() called after this.
    """
    ##########    my code   ##########
    x = self.uri.split(b'?', 1)    #split
    if len(x) == 1:           
        self.path = self.uri          #there are no parameters
    else:
        self.path, argstring = x      #argstring = my query parameters 
        params = '?' + argstring.decode()
        url += params.encode()        #convert string parameters to bytes and append them to url 
    ################################

    self.setResponseCode(FOUND)
    self.setHeader(b"location", url)
```

So, now, "location" has the new url **+** my query parameters and Redirection Service (Crossbar) is passing my parameters to the new destination, correctly.

If there is a better solution  (maybe if i could change something in crossbar and not in twisted), let me know!